# Which should I choose - "Sales report {at/on/for} April"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

1. Monthly Sales Report **at** April 2017
2. Monthly Sales Report **on** April 2017
3. Monthly Sales Report **for** April 2017

Which is suitable? I want to use it in a sentence like "Please refer to the attached 2 document for Monthly Sales at April 2017."

Comment: Hi Bee Bee. Please take a look at the [help] to learn about how this site works and what is [on topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We can help with specific questions about English and learning English. For example, we could help if you are confused about the difference between attached and attachment. If you [edit] your question to make it about what is specifically concerning you about these sentences, we might be able to reopen it.

Comment: sorry about that. act is it i need to ask, (1) Monthly Sales Report [at] April 2017 or (2)  Monthly Sales Report [on] April 2017 or  (3)  Monthly Sales Report [for] April 2017. which is suitable?

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question based on your comment, but you can do it yourself next time - just click the [edit] link. Feel free to add more detail if I didn't write your question the way you would like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the below are equivalent:

> (1) Please refer to the attached 2 documents for the monthly sales **for** April 2017
>
> (2) Please refer to the attached 2 documents for monthly sales **in** April 2017
>
> (3) Please refer to the attached 2 documents for the **April 2017 Monthly Sales**

I would like to point out the following:

- It should be "document**s**" and not "document"
- You would only capitalize "Monthly Sales" if they are in the **title** of the particular section in the attached documents. Otherwise, it would be "monthly sales". So, if you meant it as a title, (1) and (2) would have "Monthly Sales" instead of "monthly sales". However, (3) seems like it can only be a title, which is why it is capitalized.
- Since April is a whole month, it is more correct to use "for" and "in" to account for sales that happen at any time or multiple times during the month. If it was a specific *day*, then you could say "on April 21st", for example.
- I would only use **at** if it is followed by a specific location or a precise time, such as "Should I meet you *at* the restaurant?" or "Are we meeting *at* 1 o'clock?".